# URL rewrite with variables using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite a url from the website that I made but I'm not an expert using `.htaccess`. Basically I'm trying to do this:

Localhost test environment ( WAMP ):

```
http://127.0.0.1/project/index.php?p=home&l=en
```

into this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/project/en/home/
```

I made something like this but I know it is not correct:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$2/$1/$ /index.php?p=$1&l=$2 [L]
```

What's the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use $1, $2, etc. in the pattern. You must use parenthesis like so :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/$ /index.php?p=$2&l=$1
```

In the rewrited URL, $1 and $2 correspond respectively to the parenthesis in the order they appear in the regular expression.

Comment: I'm testing on my localhost using wamp and nothing works. The rewrite module is enabled

Comment: Do you get an error 500 or it's simply not working ? Could you try a basic rewrite like `RewriteRule test.php index.php` to see if the problem comes from your rule or from the module.

Answer (score 0):

also You can try with this following

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?p=$2&l=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I must change my answer because something is not working in my test environment